# Open Source ETL framework

Tags: java, python, ruby, perl, etl

I was asked to prototype two ETL frameworks. The requirements are as follows:

- Open Source
- Available to Linux
- Maintained
- Logs can be viewed on web browser (nice to have)
- Written in Perl, Python, Ruby or Java

The raw file can be anything (excel, csv, html page etc..)
The target database is MySQL.

Dont just drop names, please indicate the advantages/disadvantages based from your experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/). It has its own GUI, but if you rather use the API to do the ETL yourself it's also supported. It has proved to be very useful to me and there are a few plugins already available for it.

Answer (score 7):

One of the most popular Java based ETL would be [Talend](http://www.talend.com).

[Jaspersoft ETL](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperetl) is another one extended from Talend and has a nice eclipse based UI.

Comment: thanks, I will evaluate this.

Comment: It looks like Jaspersoft  has stopped the development of Jaspersoft ETL, it last release was in March 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com). It is written in Java and there is an open source, LGPL version of its Engine. As well it has a free version of GUI called CloverETL Community.

It can process any of the indicated sources and connects to a number of databases, including MySQL.